# Ubuntu read-only filesystem, then initramfs, how run fsck?

Tags: boot, mount, filesystem, fsck, mint

Apparently corruption got into my Ubuntu 20.04 samba server. At first it would still launch as a read-only filesystem. A number of forums and blogs recommended running fsck from a live disc. But that didn't seem to work from my Ubuntu 20.04 install USB.

After a couple more tries the corruption apparently got worse and the USB drive would not launch, giving an initramfs error instead. It seemed like I might have wipe the drive and restore from a backup until...

Comment: Please use https://unix.stackexchange.com/ for your questions. Mint is not an official Ubuntu so is not supported on AskUbuntu

Answer (score 0):

...[this](http://www.bernaerts-nicolas.fr/linux/74-ubuntu/232-ubuntu-boot-failure-initramfs) slightly old tutorial came up in a search.

Besides clearly explaining the entire process of fixing corruption, it recommended booting from a USB drive with Ubuntu Alternative 12 - because it would not mount the root drive.  That earlier OS didn't launch either but the theory proved useful.  Apparently Linux Mint, [20 "Ulyana" - Cinnamon (64-bit)](https://linuxmint.com/edition.php?id=281), does not mount the root drive.

That old machine (Mac mini late 2009) took a few minutes to launch LM from a USB drive, but once open it allowed me to confirm that dev/sdb2 was the root drive in question with...

```
$  sudo fdisk -l
```

...find that the drive did have lots of errors (without correcting) with...

```
$ sudo fsck -n /dev/sdb2
```

...then fix the errors with...

```
$ sudo fsck.ext4 -f /dev/sdb2
```

After that my machine seems to be running well.

Maybe there's an easier way to have fixed this issue, and maybe I missed something in my research, but wanted to document this in case it might be useful to others.